# Use Route53 to forward requests to parent domain

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

Our internal DNS is *company.internal*. I have *aws.company.local* running in a Route53 private hosted zone. Is it possible for me to use Route53 to resolve the parent's resources?

Not all of my VPCs have a route back to our company so I can't just forward to our internal DNS (and I'd rather not have to do resolution over that link anyways). I am trying to avoid creating caching DNS servers all over the place.

Comment: Question: with company.internal and aws.company.local, neither of those is parent or child of the other.  Can you clarify?  Assuming what you want to do can be done, how would Route 53 (or an alternative) learn about the resources you want it to resolve for you? If they are Internet-accessible, it isn't clear why you need Route 53.  If they aren't, then it isn't clear how Route 53 would learn them on your behalf.  Please advise.

Comment: They are not but the instances in AWS have access to servers that can resolve. If I could set up Route53 as a secondary server for the company.internal it would work fine (in fact this is how this currently works - I have 2 Unbound caching only boxes that can resolve either direction but I'd like to get rid of them if I can get route53 to do the work via delegation etc)

Answer (score 3):

Route 53 doesn't do what you are looking for.

Route 53 provides an authoritative -- not recursive -- DNS resolver, and it doesn't currently have the ability to do [zone transfers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone_transfer) as a slave from a master.  The only ways to update the records Route 53 will serve would be through the API or the console.

> Marco@AWS (AWS support rep) wrote, in a forum post dated 2012-03-09:
>
> “AXFR/IXFR is a feature we will consider adding in the future, but have no firm plans for at this time”
>
> — https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=88666

The resolver built in to VPC can be configured to short-circuit the normal top-down resolution of hosts via the global root servers within a specific domain using [private hosted zones](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html)... but the information has to be provisioned as authoritative inside Route 53 -- it can't be picked up and cached from elsewhere without an external mechanism to do the synching of records into Route 53.  This isn't a built-in capability.